# Record Login, Logout, System Lock/Unlock event in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, logout

I am planning a develop an application, which starts up with windows (a service perhaps) and silently records User's Login, Logout and System Lock/Unlock events..

It would be awesome if someone can give a me a tip to record their total idle time (the time where no system activity was performed by user)

I am looking for a pre-developed library or something which can help me smoothly complete the project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try it out the below code....

```
private enum WTS
{
        CONSOLE_CONNECT = 1,
        CONSOLE_DISCONNECT = 2,
        REMOTE_CONNECT = 3,
        REMOTE_DISCONNECT = 4,
        SESSION_LOGON = 5,
        SESSION_LOGOFF = 6,
        SESSION_LOCK = 7,
        SESSION_UNLOCK = 8,
        SESSION_REMOTE_CONTROL = 9
 }

protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg) {
        case WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE:
            switch (m.WParam.ToInt32) {
                case WTS.CONSOLE_CONNECT:
                    //MessageBox.Show("A session was connected to the console session.");

                    break;
                case WTS.CONSOLE_DISCONNECT:
                    //MessageBox.Show("A session was disconnected from the console session.");

                    break;
                case WTS.REMOTE_CONNECT:
                    break;
                //MessageBox.Show("A session was connected to the remote session.");
                case WTS.REMOTE_DISCONNECT:
                    break;
                //MessageBox.Show("A session was disconnected from the remote session.");
                case WTS.SESSION_LOGON:

                    break;
                //MessageBox.Show("A user has logged on to the session.")
                case WTS.SESSION_LOGOFF:
                    //MessageBox.Show("A user has logged off the session.");

                    break;
                case WTS.SESSION_LOCK:
                    //MessageBox.Show("A session has been locked.")

                    break;
                case WTS.SESSION_UNLOCK:
                    //MessageBox.Show("A session has been unlocked.")

                    break;
                case WTS.SESSION_REMOTE_CONTROL:
                    MessageBox.Show("A session has changed its remote controlled status. To determine the status, call GetSystemMetrics and check the SM_REMOTECONTROL metric.");
                    break;
            }

            break;
    }

    base.WndProc(m);
}
```

Comment: Nitin.. i m sorry to bother you once again.. but i am getting the following error "A get or set accessor expected" in Enum WTS

Comment: dear its just typo. 'Enum' to 'enum'.

Comment: I am getting some errors which building

The name 'WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE' does not exist in the current context

Cannot implicitly convert type 'WindowsApplication2.Form1.WTS' to 'method group'

Please Help !!!

Comment: declare variable as private int WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE = &H2B1

Comment: still getting an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'WindowsApplication2.Form1.WTS' to 'method group'" on every case statement e.g. case WTS.CONSOLE_CONNECT:

Comment: see my below post. I have exactly code in vb.net. Convert the below code if you are working in C#. I have shown just concept in the above post. now I have copy my working code....

Comment: Can you please attach the entire VS Solution in zip ?
or email me at kamisheikh@gmail.com
will really appreciate it.. thanks

Comment: okay.. i have converted the code to C# and still getting the same error i.e. "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Test_LoginLogout_Check.Form1.WTS' to 'method group'" 9 times

Comment: never mind.. got it..
Thanks alot Nitin.. you've been a great help :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Declare Function WTSRegisterSessionNotification Lib "Wtsapi32" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal THISSESS As Integer) As Integer
    Private Declare Function WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification Lib "Wtsapi32" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Integer

    Private Const NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS As Integer = 1
    Private Const NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION As Integer = 0
    Private Const WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE As Integer = &H2B1



    Private Enum WTS
        CONSOLE_CONNECT = 1
        CONSOLE_DISCONNECT = 2
        REMOTE_CONNECT = 3
        REMOTE_DISCONNECT = 4
        SESSION_LOGON = 5
        SESSION_LOGOFF = 6
        SESSION_LOCK = 7
        SESSION_UNLOCK = 8
        SESSION_REMOTE_CONTROL = 9
    End Enum
    Shared FileName As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Hide()
        WTSRegisterSessionNotification(Me.Handle, NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS)
        Timer1.Start()
        Me.Hide()
        FileName = Application.StartupPath + "/Data/TimeSheet_" + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + ".txt"
        System.IO.File.Create(FileName)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        Select Case m.Msg
            Case WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE
                Select Case m.WParam.ToInt32
                    Case WTS.CONSOLE_CONNECT
                        'MessageBox.Show("A session was connected to the console session.")
                        Timer1.Start()
                        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(FileName, "IN - " + lblTime.Text)
                    Case WTS.CONSOLE_DISCONNECT
                        'MessageBox.Show("A session was disconnected from the console session.")
                        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(FileName, "OUT - " + lblTime.Text + vbCrLf)
                        Timer1.Stop()
                    Case WTS.REMOTE_CONNECT
                        'MessageBox.Show("A session was connected to the remote session.")
                    Case WTS.REMOTE_DISCONNECT
                        'MessageBox.Show("A session was disconnected from the remote session.")
                    Case WTS.SESSION_LOGON
                        Timer1.Start()
                        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(FileName, "IN - " + lblTime.Text)
                        'MessageBox.Show("A user has logged on to the session.")
                    Case WTS.SESSION_LOGOFF
                        'MessageBox.Show("A user has logged off the session.")
                        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(FileName, "OUT - " + lblTime.Text + vbCrLf)
                        Timer1.Stop()
                    Case WTS.SESSION_LOCK
                        'MessageBox.Show("A session has been locked.")
                        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(FileName, "OUT - " + lblTime.Text + vbCrLf)
                        Timer1.Stop()
                    Case WTS.SESSION_UNLOCK
                        'MessageBox.Show("A session has been unlocked.")
                        Timer1.Start()
                        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(FileName, "IN - " + lblTime.Text)
                        If m_clsBalloonEvents Is Nothing Then
                            'allow our ballon class to create the event class for us, hooking into the notify icon that will 
                            'be associated with the balloons...
                            m_clsBalloonEvents = Balloon.HookBalloonEvents(niMain)
                            'add handlers for the events that we are concerned with in this application...
                            AddHandler m_clsBalloonEvents.BallonClicked, AddressOf BalloonClicked
                            AddHandler m_clsBalloonEvents.BallonHidden, AddressOf BalloonHidden
                        End If
                        Balloon.DisplayBalloon(niMain, "Today's Time", lblTime.Text, CType(IIf(False, Balloon.BalloonMessageTypes.Error, Balloon.BalloonMessageTypes.Info), Balloon.BalloonMessageTypes))
                    Case WTS.SESSION_REMOTE_CONTROL
                        MessageBox.Show("A session has changed its remote controlled status. To determine the status, call GetSystemMetrics and check the SM_REMOTECONTROL metric.")
                End Select

        End Select

        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
```