# monitor user activities using c#

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, monitoring

I am developing an application, which monitor user activities. I need to know the login,logoff,lock and unlock time of each user. How can I fetch these informations from the local machine using C#.

Please note: I am not asking first login and last logout time. I need the entire user activity including windows lock and unlock. then only I can find out the actual working hour. please let me know if there is any way to do this

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is pure evil!

Comment: Did you see the following question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457852/record-login-logout-system-lock-unlock-event-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this could be done by checking SystemEvent_SessionSwitch, this code will tell you when someone left the desk and returned to their desk. (Code example written by [Timoty Carter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4660/timothy-carter))

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);

    void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock)
        { 
            //I left my desk
        }
        else if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock)
        { 
            //I returned to my desk
        }
    }
```

To find out the time they logged in or out you can just check the user object from the current machine [UserPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public DateTime UserLogon(string username)
{
   // create your domain context
   PrincipalContext domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

   // find the user
   UserPrincipal foundUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, IdentityType.Name, username);

   //Return time for last logon
   return foundUser.LastLogon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SystemEvents` class. It provides events for all user activities like logout, lock, logoff etc.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)